# Calling each lines of stings to %s in Python

Tags: python, string

I have one csv file containing multiple usernames by each row. With reading this csv, I am trying to call each username by using '%s' one by one from each row to search the tweets of these usernames within the time range. I tried to store usernames to keyword variable and call those that into %s but this approach seems not working. Could anyone help to find the error here?

Here's my current code using for loop below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('list_of_username.csv')

maxTweets = 100000
tweets = []
tdf = None

csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

keyword = [j for j in df.username]

for j in tqdm(enumerate(keyword)):
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from: %s lang:ko since:2017-08-07 until:2018-02-06 -filter:replies' % keyword).get_items()):
        if i > maxTweets :
                break      
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.username, tweet.date, tweet])
csvFile.close()
```

[Here's my data in list_of_username.csv look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlM3z.png)

Comment: could you post a sample of your csv please?

Comment: Please don't post images of data. That would require anyone who want to help you to sit down and transcribe your images in order to test the solution. Provide the data as formatted text instead.

Comment: keyword is a list; you probably meant `%j[1]` instead of `%keyword`.

Comment: @Demi-Lune Thanks. It worked.